# Problem updating a state using setInterval in React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a function called `getRandomHexagram()` which returns a random 6-character string that is used for props in my `<hexagram string={stringstate} />` component in my I Ching divination app.

I also have a function called `resettimer()` which retrieves this random 6-character string multiple times and passes it to my component within a few seconds, so that while `setInterval` is running, the component will keep changing its appearance until `clearInterval` is called.

I would like to continuously update the state using `resettimer()` function run until it ends, and then use the new state in another function together with `clearInterval`.

What is strange to me is that while the `if` portion of the timer is running, the component continuously updates as it should. But when I try to call the final state in the `} else {` statement together with `clearInterval`, console always shows that `stringstate` is still `"VVVVVV"`, or whatever was the last prop that my component used in my previous click, NOT what my component is currently using.

```
function getRandomHexagram() {
  const flipcoins = () => {
    return (
      (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 2) +
      (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 2) +
      (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 2)
    );
  };
  const drawline = (coinvalue) => {
    let line;
    if (coinvalue == 6) {line = "B";}
    if (coinvalue == 7) {line = "V";}
    if (coinvalue == 8) {line = "P";}
    if (coinvalue == 9) {line = "W";}
    return line;
  };
  return (
    drawline(flipcoins()) +
    drawline(flipcoins()) +
    drawline(flipcoins()) +
    drawline(flipcoins()) +
    drawline(flipcoins()) +
    drawline(flipcoins())
  );
}

function App() {

const [stringstate, setStringstate] = useState("VVVVVV");

  function resettimer() {
    var timesrun = 0;
    var randomtime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 10;
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      timesrun += 1;
      if (timesrun < randomtime) {
        thisString = getRandomHexagram();
        setStringstate(thisString);

        console.log("the current permutation is: " + thisString);
        // console and component shows this correctly.
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval);

        console.log("the final state state is: " + stringstate);
        // Call another function here using the NEW stringstate
        // But console shows that stringstate is still showing 
        // the old state of VVVVVV despite my component showing otherwise
      }
    }, 100);
  }

... ...

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button onClick={() => resettimer()}>
      <Hexagram string={stringstate} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

When the button is clicked and the function invoked, my console shows this:

```
the current permutation is: VPPVPB
the current permutation is: VPPPVV
the current permutation is: BPBVBV
the current permutation is: VVPVPV
the current permutation is: PPBVPV
the current permutation is: PPPBBB
the current permutation is: VVPPPV
the final state state is: VVVVVV
```

Any idea why this is happening? Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: The function you pass to setInterval has strigState in it's closure but that function isn't passed again to setInterval when the component re renders so you are logging a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/)

You could just use the value of thisString instead.